# Can a body be accelerated without the application of a force, but rather just by a transfer of momentum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, acceleration

If we suppose that a car moving with uniform velocity hits a stationary person on a road, even though the car has no acceleration and exerts no force on the person, the person moves, falls back due to the transfer of momentum from the car. Then, hasn't the person accelerated, by no application of force? But doesn't it violate the statement "no mass can change its state of motion unless a force acts on it"?

Answer (score 3):

No it does not. When the car strikes the person, it decelerates. Remember the definition of a force as in Newton’s second law,

$$F = \frac{dp}{dt} = m \frac{dv}{dt} = ma$$

Because there is a change of momentum (for both the car and the person) at the impact, then there is a force.

The motion of both the car and person have changed, even though before the collision there are no forces. During the collision, there are.

Comment: So does that mean that whenever there's a collision there's always a change in velocity? No matter how small the Collison?

Comment: @SamyakKhobragade Yes, when a collision occurs there is always an acceleration and change in momentum. Except for unrealistically ideal cases such as collisions with an object of infinite mass.

Comment: Right, so I could say that any body said to be moving in uniform velocity on earth atleast, is actually accelerating and can't ever be in uniform motion since there are infinite collisions happening with the air particles present there? Ofcourse we need not account them for obvious reasons but this in real is true right?

Answer (score 0):

No. If momentum changes, there is a force acting on your system. A net force acting on a body **is defined** as a change in momentum overt time. Specifically, $$\sum \vec {\mathbf{F}}_{\rm ext}\equiv \dfrac{\mathrm d\vec {\mathbf{p}}}{\mathrm dt} \approx \dfrac{\Delta \vec {\mathbf{p}}}{\Delta t}$$ where **p** denotes the momentum.

For $dm/dt=0$, you get the famous $\sum F=ma$ equation. When there is an acceleration (change in velocity), then there must be a net force.

When two objects collide, there will always be a contact force (normal force) between them. That is why objects that collide can have their velocities changed --  a force is exerted on them.

As per Newton's first law, an object at rest/moving at a constant velocity will continue doing so unless acted upon by an unbalanced force.

Answer (score 0):

Collisions are indeed often treated in physics problems as instantaneous (billiard balls being a favorite example). In such calculations, force is not used, because it would be infinite; rather transfers of momentum are modeled as impulses delivered instantaneously. But this is all a simplification; in real life there's always a finite force acting over a finite timr.